# How to Display Background watermark on trading view with pine code

Tags: pine-script

How to display a customized water mark text on trading view charts?

Answer (score 0):

This capability is not available in Pine.
Something similar I've seen done is display a custom label at the bottom/top of the chart around the current candle.